# Any short cut to get the current mouse cursor position function name in textmate?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

For example....

```
function other_function ()
{

}

function myfunction()
{
       |  //<--- it is the cursor

}

function another_function ()
{

}
```

is there any short cut for me to get the myfunction? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want it in the clipboard in order to use it somewhere or do you want to just see it?

Comment: Are you still interested in an answer to this question? I think it should be possible to write a bundle command that achieves what you require.

Comment: I would love to have this. I have several spaghetti code files that could REALLY REALLY use this. It would speed my life up greatly.